# Is it possible to scale a drag image

Tags: javascript, css

I am doing drag and drop and want to use a different drag image than the default. But I would also like to scale the size of the drag image depending on the size of the element where the drag starts. I have tried doing the following:

```
<div id="drag-with-image" draggable="true">drag me</div>
<script>
document.getElementById("drag-with-image").addEventListener("dragstart", function(e) {
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = "https://www.w3schools.com/css/paris.jpg";
    img.style.width = "60px";
    img.style.height = "40px";
    e.dataTransfer.setDragImage(img, 0, 0);
}, false);
</script>
```

But the drag image is always displayed as full size.

Is there any way the drag image size can be scaled dynamically?

Comment: Does my [solution below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60880880/9060223) answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to scale a custom drag image.

### The Problem

If you're using `setDragImage` with an image element, what will be drawn is the image in its intrinsic size (content size before any modification). This means that setting the image size doesn't help. However, as mentioned in [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer/setDragImage), you can also set a drag image to be something else:

> If Element is an img element, then set the drag data store bitmap to the element's image (at its intrinsic size); otherwise, set the drag data store bitmap to an image generated from the given element (the exact mechanism for doing so is not currently specified).

Furthermore, it also mentions that the "other elements" can be any visible element or even a `<canvas>`:

> However, if a custom image is desired, the DataTransfer.setDragImage() method can be used to set the custom image to be used. The image will typically be an  element but it can also be a  or any other visible element.

---

### Solution

To draw an image that is smaller than its intrinsic size and setting it to drag image, you can:

- Load the image to an image element
- Create a canvas to be drawn with the image
- When drawing to the canvas, adjust the width and height of the drawn image accordingly

Here's a working example.

```js
document.getElementById('drag-with-image').addEventListener('dragstart', function(e) {
    var img = document.createElement('img')
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
    // Setting img src
    img.src = 'https://www.w3schools.com/css/paris.jpg'
    
    // Drawing to canvas with a smaller size
    canvas.width = img.width * 0.1
    canvas.height = img.height * 0.1
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
    
    // Setting drag image with drawn canvas image
    e.dataTransfer.setDragImage(canvas, 0, 0)
}, false)
```

```html
<div id="drag-with-image" draggable="true">drag me</div>
```